# ActiveRecord query to retrieve child objects based on a deeply nested condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following relationships:

```
Teacher hasMany Students hasOne Desk
```

I need to retrieve all Student objects, using an instance of Teacher, based on a condition in Desk. I have this working using the Student model, but I can't get it to work using an instance of Teacher.

Working:

```
Student.joins(:desk).where(:id => some_id, :desks => {:some_field=>true})
```

Was thinking something along these lines might work, but I can't get the syntax right

```
teacher.students.where(:desk.some_field=>true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you'd do to get all students associated with a particular teacher based on the a condition within the desk instance associated with a student:

```
Teacher.first.students.joins(:desk).where(desk: {some_field: 1})
```

Which in SQL is this:

```
  SELECT  `teachers`.* FROM `teachers`
  SELECT `students`.* FROM `students` INNER JOIN `desks` ON `desks`.`students_id` = `students`.`id` WHERE `students`.`teacher_id` = some_id AND `desks`.`some_field` = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also, to get this query to work on an instance of Teacher, instead of "Teacher.first", "teacher" works. I also needed to use symbols in the where clause. Not sure if that's AR version dependent or not.

Comment: Yup! I didn't want to make any assumptions on `teacher` so for the sake of the example I just queried the first teacher and joined on that :)